# How to notify a NativeScript Vue app when a Key Event is captured at the Activity level?

Tags: android, nativescript-vue

I have extended androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity to capture key event in a NativeScript-Vue project. Now, my problem becomes how to notify the Vue app that a key even has been captured. More importantly, what is the right way to notify the Vue app ('cause I can think of some not too correct way to solve the problem)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, I settled at the most straightforward solution. In activity.android.js, I implemented a simple listener pattern:

```
androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.extend("org.myApp.MainActivity", {
    keyUpListener: null,
    registerListener(name, func) {
        if (name == "keyUp") {
            this.keyUpListener = func;
        }
        else {
            throw new Error(`There's not a type of listener called ${name}.`);
        }
    },
    unregisterListener(name) {
        if (name == "keyUp") {
            this.keyUpListener = null;
        }
        else {
            throw new Error(`There's not a type of listener called ${name}.`);
        }
    },
    onKeyUp: function (keyCode, event) {
        if (this.keyUpListener) {
            let result = this.keyUpListener(keyCode, event);
            if (result != null) {
                return result;
            }
        }
        return superProto.onKeyUp.call(this, keyCode, event);
    },
    [... snip ...]
```

Then, in my .vue file, I simply register a listener to the extended Activity:

```
import { android as androidApp } from "tns-core-modules/application";

[... snip ...]

androidApp.foregroundActivity.registerListener(
        "keyUp",
        this.onKeyUp
);
```

If there's a better **Vue** or **NativeScript** way to handle this problem, I would love to learn about it.